# Test iAd showing up on simulator, iPhone device but not iPad device

Tags: iphone, ipad, iad, simulator

I have a tricky problem here... I hope someone will be able to help me because it's driving me  crazy.

I have an Universal app that displays iAd. It is working fine on the simulator and also on an iPhone. But when I try out on an iPad it always give me this f***** error :

```
Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad inventory unavailable" UserInfo=0xd6a37e0 {ADInternalErrorCode=3, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad inventory unavailable}
```

There is absolutely no reasonable explanation for that. My ad banner is not displayed in a scrollView or some crazy hierarchies. And this is really annoying. I don't know what to do and I would like to submit my app quickly :)

I found many thread with this problem and I tried there solutions: to remove the app from the device, to clean the targets, everything! Nothing worked. I tried to change the iPad clock and still nothing.

Any help would be really appreciated!

As asked here is the code to create the banner:

```
- (void) createIAdBanner {

//if(isIPad) return;

if(!iAdBanner) {

    iAdBanner = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, (isIPad)?1024:320, (isIPad)?66.:50.)];
    iAdBanner.delegate = self;
    iAdBanner.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:(isIPad)?ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
    [adContainer addSubview:iAdBanner];
    [iAdBanner release];
}
}
```

Comment: By the way the sample codes from Apple give the same error on my iPad. I guess that it's a problem on Apple's side... Or maybe related to my iPad somehow. I read that the clock could be a problem. I will try on other devices.

Comment: Thomas, I am having the same issue on an iPad 2 running iOS 4.3. How did you resolve your issue?

Comment: I put my same answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579138/iad-banner-shows-test-ad-on-simulator-but-not-on-device

I hope can be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Is your app a universal one??

Because iPhone apps running in compatibility mode on iPad doesn't display iAds. If you really want the ads to be working on iPad as well,make sure you design a universal app....

From the official documentation